# Importing massive data into SQL Azure Database with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlbulkcopy

Straight to the point, I have a Web Application forged in PHP.
I want to import files sized aprox 2 GB or more into Azure SQL Database, but I want to do this programatically using PHP.

I just started searching for helps in this track and already discovered that Azure Database doesn't have a BULK LOAD or BULK INSERT function which I was planning to use...

So, is there a way to import that amount of data to Azure, with PHP?

Comment: It depends. Are you the server owner? As in, do you have administrative rights to it?

Comment: Anyway, if you look over here, it is possible to do bulk inserts to Azure Databases: https://thecodegarden.net/bulk-insert-azure-sql/ With the PHP [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function you could perform the required commands on the server. If you have the access rights that is ofc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Yes, I'm the server owner.... So, if use PHP exec() function, like exec(BCP <databasename>.dbo.<tablename> IN <localfolder>\<filename>.txt -S <servername>;
-U <username>@<servername> -P <password> -c)... that should do it?

Comment: Important to say... my php application ISN'T hosted in Azure... Anyway, I'll give it a try...

Comment: No you need to create a batch file (.bat) with the command and than `exec("script.bat");`

Comment: Keep in mind though that this will launch the command prompt on the server and it will do it's job. PHP won't give you any ouput on whether it was succesfull or not or when the job is finished

Comment: Thank you again. That linked the things so now I can make this process automatic... about the bat file, I just tried running exec() with the BCP command directly into his string parameter and worked. Also, I found some others questions about exec() that claim to do get a response message...